# Only run skaction if collision is in view

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game where if there is a collision between two of the same bodies then a sound plays. I've got this part working fine, but I only want the sound to play if the collision happens in the view. I have a scrolling background and collisions further ahead are making a noise.

Is there anyway to limit this sound from only playing when a collision happens in view?

Right now i'm using this code:

```
let rocksCollide = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("rocks.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

 if nodeB.name == "SMALLASTEROID" && nodeA.name == "SMALLASTEROID"{
            runAction(rocksCollide)
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SKNode has a position property which is a CGPoint. The screen is an SKNode which has a frame property which is a CGRect. There exists a function CGrectContainsPoint(CGRect, CGPoint)

Comment: ok thank you il google that, im still new to swift and spritekit so im finding it hard with things like this where to start so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `node.position` is inside the visible frame. For example.

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(visibleFrame, nodeA.position)) {
   // Play sound.     
}
```

Comment: to check the visible frame would this be view.bounds?

Comment: how are you doing your scrolling?

Comment: im using the update function and scrolling vertically with: 

self.background.position = CGPointMake(self.background.position.x, -(player.position.y - 180)/200)

Comment: i thought i had this working, but its still not doing it.

Comment: how are you calculating the visibleFrame? it should be calculated from `self.background.position`.